# AM Container is running beyond virtual memory limits

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I was playing with distributed shell application (hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.1.2).
This is the error I'm receiving at the moment.

```
13/01/01 17:09:09 INFO distributedshell.Client: Got application report from ASM for, appId=5, clientToken=null, appDiagnostics=Application application_1357039792045_0005 failed 1 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1357039792045_0005_000001 exited with  exitCode: 143 due to: Container [pid=24845,containerID=container_1357039792045_0005_01_000001] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 77.8mb of 512.0mb physical memory used; 1.1gb of 1.0gb virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1357039792045_0005_01_000001 :
|- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
|- 24849 24845 24845 24845 (java) 165 12 1048494080 19590 /usr/java/bin/java -Xmx512m org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.ApplicationMaster --container_memory 128 --num_containers 1 --priority 0 --shell_command ping --shell_args localhost --debug
|- 24845 23394 24845 24845 (bash) 0 0 108654592 315 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/bin/java -Xmx512m org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.ApplicationMaster --container_memory 128 --num_containers 1 --priority 0 --shell_command ping --shell_args localhost --debug 1>/tmp/logs/application_1357039792045_0005/container_1357039792045_0005_01_000001/AppMaster.stdout 2>/tmp/logs/application_1357039792045_0005/container_1357039792045_0005_01_000001/AppMaster.stderr
```

The interesting part is that, there seems to be no problem with the setup, since a simple `ls` or `uname` command completed successfully and the output was available in the container2 stdout.

Regarding the setup, `yarn.nodenamager.vmem-pmem-ratio` is `3` and the total physical memory available is 2GB, which I thinks is more than enough for example to run.

For the command in question, the "ping localhost" generated two replies, as it can be seen from the `containerlogs/container_1357039792045_0005_01_000002/721917/stdout/?start=-4096.`

So, what could be the problem?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok, found out. Increase the master memry parameter to more tan 750MB and you will succeed running the YARN app.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention what parameter and any reference where you found that.

Answer (score 15):

From the error message, you can see that you're using more virtual memory than your current limit of 1.0gb. This can be resolved in two ways:

**Disable Virtual Memory Limit Checking**

YARN will simply ignore the limit; in order to do this, add this to your `yarn-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>Whether virtual memory limits will be enforced for containers.</description>
</property>
```

The default for this setting is `true`.

**Increase Virtual Memory to Physical Memory Ratio**

In your `yarn-site.xml` change this to a higher value than is currently set

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
  <value>5</value>
  <description>Ratio between virtual memory to physical memory when setting memory limits for containers. Container allocations are expressed in terms of physical memory, and virtual memory usage is allowed to exceed this allocation by this ratio.</description>
</property>
```

The default is `2.1`

You could also increase the amount of physical memory you allocate to a container.

Make sure you don't forget to restart yarn after you change the config.

Comment: this solution worked exactly what is outined by tmlye.  Thanks a ton! Saved a lot of my time. Note - you must restart yarn stop-yarn.sh/start-yarn.sh

Answer (score 13):

No need to change the cluster configuration. I found out that just providing the extra parameter

```
-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096
```

to distcp helped for me.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life :) I thought I'd have to change configuration and restart the whole cluster, but increasing memory worked in my case as well. Also running `distcp`.

Comment: Glad it helped! I realize that the original question is not about `distcp`, but I think it's basically the same problem which should have the same solution.

Comment: Also helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Tez framework, it is must to set the below parameters in Tez-site.xml

```
tez.am.resource.memory.mb
tez.task.resource.memory.mb
tez.am.java.opts
```

And in Yarn-site.xml

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio
```

All these parameters are mandatory to set

Answer (score 0):

You can change this to a higher value than default 1 GB in your yarn-site.xml

yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb

Answer (score 0):

In practice i have seen this problem occur when running queries against large tables or tables that contain large number of files/small-files or un-bucketed tables or querying large number of partitions.

The problem occurs when Tez tries to calculate how many mappers it needs to spawn and while doing this calculation it tends to go OOM due to the default (1gb) is too less.

The way to fix this is to not set `tez.am.resource.memory.mb` to say 2gb or 4gb.
Also, one more very important thing is that this setting cannot be set from within the hive query as its too late by then. The AM is the first container to get spawned by yarn, so setting this in hive query is not useful.

The setting needs to be either set in *-site.xml or while spawning the hive shell like below:

`hive --hiveconf tez.am.resource.memory.mb=2048 my-large-query.hql`

In the above example am signalling yarn to spawn the AM to be of 2gb instead of whatever the default is.

Reference: http://moi.vonos.net/bigdata/hive-cli-memory/